# libssh.so.4 error undefined symbol: EVP_PKEY_get_base_id

Tags: kubuntu, 22.04

I have just upgraded Kubuntu 21.10 to 22.04. I get an error thrown by libssh.so.4: undefined symbol: EVP_PKEY_get_base_id, version OPENSSL_3.0.0. This affects Plasma (5.24.4) and several of the related components, Megasync etc. I am running an amd64 system.

openssl 3.0.2 is installed

libssh.so.4.8.7 is installed

I had thought it was related to libssl1.1 but I uninstalled this with no change.

Can anyone suggest where I can start to try and fix this?

Answer (score 2):

problem solved. I had legacy libcrypt.so file in /usr/local/lib as well as a legacy libssl.so file.

Comment: How you figured that, and how solved the problem?